# Set GCP Service account details in environment variable in .net

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, service-accounts

I want to connect from azure web app to google cloud platform project. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#wlif-key), I need to set an environment variable - `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` - to the location of json file containing the private key downloaded from gcp project for service account. I am saving the json file on a blob and setting its location in the environment variable, but it prepends the name of the current working directory to the blob path.

How can I avoid uploading the json file to the repository . I am using .net.

The blob path is changed from "https:/myfirstblob.blob.core.windows.net/mygcp-service-account/creds.json" is changed to "C:\mycurrentworkingdirectory...\..\https:\myfirstblob.blob.core.windows.net\mygcp-service-account\creds.json"

Comment: Give the service account the “Service account user” permission and impersonate the service account when you test/run your application. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/use-service-account-impersonation. This way you dont download they key itself you just use a temporary token with a temp path set by the gcloud command itself. Then, you can set the env variable to this temp path.

Comment: Thanks @FahedSabellioglu how to handle in production?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following approach to avoid setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` - I added the json properties in my configuration file. The values of which I can pick from azure key vault. There is a provision in google clients to set credentials using `JsonCredentialParameters`. Here I am using PredictionServiceClientBuilder client.

```
 var parameters = new JsonCredentialParameters
 {
     Type = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.Type,
     ProjectId = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.ProjectId,
     PrivateKeyId = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.PrivateKeyId,
     PrivateKey = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.PrivateKey.Replace("\\n", "\n"),
     ClientEmail = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.ClientEmail,
     ClientId = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.ClientId,
     TokenUrl = _gcpServiceAccountConfiguration.TokenUrl
 };

await new PredictionServiceClientBuilder
            {
                Settings = settings,
                Endpoint = "",
                // Below is the main part          
                GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromJsonParameters(parameters)     
        }.BuildAsync();
```

Below 2 alternative properties are also provided by google clients for setting credentials -

```
new PredictionServiceClientBuilder {
    CredentialsPath = "C:\\mypath\\creds.json"
}
```

AND

```
string jsonCreds = "{\r\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",\r\n  \"project_id\": \"my-project\",\r\n  \"private_key_id\": ..}";
new PredictionServiceClientBuilder {
    JsonCredentials = jsonCreds
}
```

Comment: If you use azure, prefer workload identity federation. Using service account key file, even stored in a vault, is not a good security practice